# Delphi Clientdataset Lookup/Aggregate

Tags: delphi, aggregate, lookup, tclientdataset

I need a little help with ClientDatasets in Delphi.

What I want to achieve is a grid showing customers, where one of the columns shows the number of orders for each customer.
I put a ClientDataset on a form and load Customers.xml from Delphi demo-data.
Another ClienDataset is loaded with orders.xml.
Relatively simple, I can define an aggregate on the orders CDS showing the total amount per customer (or the count). (See Cary Jensens article on this: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29272) 
The problem is getting this aggregate result from orders dataset into the customer dataset.

It is kind of an reverse lookup, since there is a 1-n relationship between customers and orders, not an n-1 as normally in lookup scenarios.

Any ideas ?

Søren

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you could define a calculated field in the customers dataset which would simply take the value of the aggregated field in the orders dataset.

Comment: Hi TOndrej,
that is a feasible solution, I think I wil go with that.
Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a **Master** (Customers) - **Detail** (Orders) relation?
It's not a lookup situation.

Comment: Hi Francois,
The Master-detail relation is incompatible with the aggregate function, since it redefines the Index-definitions on the orders dataset.